# How Grails plugin hard depenencies work?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-plugin

I found plugin that has dependencies defined in BuildConfig.groovy and same dependencies duplicated in plugin manifest like this:

```
def dependsOn = [foo: "* > 1.0"]
```

Are this definitions same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dependsOn` shouldn't be used in 2.0 and higher. We no longer use that setting - dependencies are specified in BuildConfig.groovy and those are used to generate a POM file when releasing the plugin. The POM is used when installing the plugin to determine jar and plugin dependencies.

Comment: Thank Burt! I found that some plugins that was updated to Grails 2.0 still contains dependsOn.
And this causes errors during dependencies resolution.
It might be good to mention about this pitfall in documentation.
I found only Piter Ledbrook article with instruction for plugin updateing http://pledbrook.github.io/grails-howtos/en/upgradeToGrails2.html and it not contains awareness about dependsOn